# How to make a certain non-unique column, an index in my PySpark Dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe: df, that has a non-unique column named: date_index.

date_index takes values as shown below. I need to make this column, an index to df.

date_index values:6/27/2018 7:45, 6/28/2018 7:45,6/28/2018 7:45,  6/28/2018 7:45, 6/29/2018 7:45

I would like to convert the below python command to it's PySpark equivalent.

```
df.set_index('date_index',inplace=True)
```

Futher clarification:
I'd like the below change to take place in my dataframe, using pyspark commands.

Dataframe before:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwTld.jpg)

Dataframe after:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCTNb.jpg)

Comment: Are you looking for an equivalent of the Pandas indexing feature in Spark ? I'm afraid Spark doesn't have that. In which context do you need that ?

Comment: If not equivalent, is there a way to make 'date_index' column, the index of the dataframe df using pyspark?

Comment: I believe that @pfc wanted to say that (Py)Spark has no concept of index. So it is a bit unclear what you're looking for and additional clarifications are required, for potential answers to provide meaningful suggestions.

Comment: I've added pictures of the dataframe before set_index is performed and after set_index is performed in python. I just need to get the same end result using pyspark. Kindly advise

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is not yet possible in PySpark.